# How to create binary file in Perl?

Tags: perl

`od -x test` shows:

`0000000 457f 464c 0102 0001`

Now I want to use Perl to create such file.

```
open FH,'>','test_1';
#syswrite(FH,0x457f464c01020001); # not work
print FH 0x457f464c01020001;      # not work
```

How to create binary file in Perl?

Comment: For what it's worth, your code does "work", but it doesn't do what you want. It converts the hex representation to its internal number format (probably losing a bunch of bits in the conversion), then prints the decimal representation of the number. Think about it - you would hardly want `print 1;` to print a ctrl-A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a binary file, one uses

```
open (my $fh, '>:raw', $qfn)
```

To place

```
45 7f 46 4c 01 02 00 01
```

in that file, one can use any of the following:

```
# Starting with a string of those bytes.
print $fh "\x45\x7f\x46\x4c\x01\x02\x00\x01";

# Starting with a hex representation of the file.
print $fh pack('H*', '457f464c01020001');

# Starting with the bytes.
print $fh map chr, 0x45, 0x7f, 0x46, 0x4c, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01;

# Starting with the bytes.
print $fh pack('C*', 0x45, 0x7f, 0x46, 0x4c, 0x01, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
open(my $out, '>:raw', 'test_1.bin') or die "Unable to open: $!";
print $out pack('s<',255) ;
close($out);
```

also you can look at the perl pack functions [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)

Comment: Alternative to set file to binary mode:

`binmode(FH);`

It's worth understanding what 's' represents (for OP):

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html

Answer (score 1):

```
print FH pack 'H*', '457f464c01020001'
```

Answer (score 0):

`print FH "\x45\x7f\x46\x4c\x01\x02\x00\x01"` is another way. See [Quote and Quote-like Operators in perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop#Quote_and_Quote-like_Operators) for more information about escape sequences available in strings. `\x` works like it does in C... except that Perl has an extended syntax that goes beyond `\xff`.